# Python BeautifulSoup - How to extract text from http/xml tags in "linear" order

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup, xml-parsing

I have a block of text like so where I need to extract the text from (this is mocked up data):

```
<text>
            <table>
              <tbody>
<tr><td>&#xA0;</td><td><content styleCode="Bold">General Adult Exam</content></td></tr>
<tr><td><content styleCode="Bold">Constitutional:</content></td><td>General Appearance: healthy-appearing, well-nourished, well-developed</td></tr>
<tr><td><content styleCode="Bold">Lungs:</content></td><td>Respiratory effort: no dyspnea. Auscultation: breath sounds normal, good air movement, CTA except as noted, no wheezing, no rales/crackles, no rhonchi</td></tr>
<tr><td><content styleCode="Bold">Cardiovascular:</content></td><td>Heart Auscultation: RRR, normal S1, normal S2, no murmurs, no rubs, no gallops. Neck vessels: no carotid bruits</td></tr>
<tr><td><content styleCode="Bold">Musculoskeletal::</content></td><td>Joints, Bones, and Muscles: ; She has decreased range of motion especially to abduction with some pain on internal rotation</td></tr>
</tbody>
            </table>
          </text>
```

Reading it in (note my actual string has no newlines):

```
medsoup = '<text>            <table>              <tbody><tr><td>&#xA0;</td><td><content styleCode="Bold">General Adult Exam</content></td></tr><tr><td><content styleCode="Bold">Constitutional:</content></td><td>General Appearance: healthy-appearing, well-nourished, well-developed</td></tr><tr><td><content styleCode="Bold">Lungs:</content></td><td>Respiratory effort: no dyspnea. Auscultation: breath sounds normal, good air movement, CTA except as noted, no wheezing, no rales/crackles, no rhonchi</td></tr><tr><td><content styleCode="Bold">Cardiovascular:</content></td><td>Heart Auscultation: RRR, normal S1, normal S2, no murmurs, no rubs, no gallops. Neck vessels: no carotid bruits</td></tr><tr><td><content styleCode="Bold">Musculoskeletal::</content></td><td>Joints, Bones, and Muscles: ; She has decreased range of motion especially to abduction with some pain on internal rotation</td></tr></tbody>            </table>          </text>'
medsoup  
Out[358]: '<text>            <table>              <tbody><tr><td>&#xA0;</td><td><content styleCode="Bold">General Adult Exam</content></td></tr><tr><td><content styleCode="Bold">Constitutional:</content></td><td>General Appearance: healthy-appearing, well-nourished, well-developed</td></tr><tr><td><content styleCode="Bold">Lungs:</content></td><td>Respiratory effort: no dyspnea. Auscultation: breath sounds normal, good air movement, CTA except as noted, no wheezing, no rales/crackles, no rhonchi</td></tr><tr><td><content styleCode="Bold">Cardiovascular:</content></td><td>Heart Auscultation: RRR, normal S1, normal S2, no murmurs, no rubs, no gallops. Neck vessels: no carotid bruits</td></tr><tr><td><content styleCode="Bold">Musculoskeletal::</content></td><td>Joints, Bones, and Muscles: ; She has decreased range of motion especially to abduction with some pain on internal rotation</td></tr></tbody>            </table>          </text>'
```

**Question:** How would I extract the text from each tag in "linear" order, in how a human would read it, from left to right, with whitespace in between each instance of text?

**What I've Tried**

If I try to use BeautifulSoup's get_text(), it's very close, except I need newlines (or at the very least spaces) between each separate text entry.  Notice how `General Adult ExamConstitutional:General Appearance:` all runs together, when I need `General Adult Exam Constitutional: General Appearance:`

```
parsed_soup = BeautifulSoup(medsoup, 'lxml')
parsed_soup.get_text().strip()
Out[340]: 'General Adult ExamConstitutional:General Appearance: healthy-appearing, well-nourished, well-developedLungs:Respiratory effort: no dyspnea. Auscultation: breath sounds normal, good air movement, CTA except as noted, no wheezing, no rales/crackles, no rhonchiCardiovascular:Heart Auscultation: RRR, normal S1, normal S2, no murmurs, no rubs, no gallops. Neck vessels: no carotid bruitsMusculoskeletal::Joints, Bones, and Muscles: ; She has decreased range of motion especially to abduction with some pain on internal rotation'
```

If I try to iterate over individual elements in the soup, in the hopes of adding in whitespace after each piece of text, I get a weird thing where it seems there's only one element to iterate.

```
for i, ele in enumerate(parsed_soup):
    print(i, ele, '\n')


0 <html><body><text> <table> <tbody><tr><td> </td><td><content stylecode="Bold">General Adult Exam</content></td></tr><tr><td><content stylecode="Bold">Constitutional:</content></td><td>General Appearance: healthy-appearing, well-nourished, well-developed</td></tr><tr><td><content stylecode="Bold">Lungs:</content></td><td>Respiratory effort: no dyspnea. Auscultation: breath sounds normal, good air movement, CTA except as noted, no wheezing, no rales/crackles, no rhonchi</td></tr><tr><td><content stylecode="Bold">Cardiovascular:</content></td><td>Heart Auscultation: RRR, normal S1, normal S2, no murmurs, no rubs, no gallops. Neck vessels: no carotid bruits</td></tr><tr><td><content stylecode="Bold">Musculoskeletal::</content></td><td>Joints, Bones, and Muscles: ; She has decreased range of motion especially to abduction with some pain on internal rotation</td></tr></tbody> </table> </text></body></html>
```

I've also tried `next_siblings` and `next_element` to try to iterate over the tags, I can't get either to work.

Comment: A XML or HTML document is really a *directed graph* comprising of elements containing elements and so on. You are asking to traverse the nodes in *depth-first order*.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, something like this can be done with lxml, if you can use it.